# Problema con web panel en propiedad Login object for web - Genexus

Tags: genexus

Aplique gam a mi proyecto en genexus 16 pero cuando intento asignar el web panel home como login object for web este no me lo permite asignar (ni ningun otro web panel de mi aplicacion) y deja por defecto el GamExmpleLogin.
El home ya fue fijado con la propiedad set startup object.
Agradezco si alguien sabe cual pueda ser la razón.

[image: Login Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el borde derecho de la propiedad te tiene que aparecer un pequeño botón con 3 puntitos. Ese botón te abre un diálogo de donde puedes seleccionar el web panel a poner como [Login Object](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15590). Ten en cuenta que el Web Panel en cuestion tiene que tener la propiedad [Main program](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7407) en **True** e [Integrated Security Level](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15214) en **None**

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió tu comentario :), es que soy nueva en esto de genexus.